# How to build a check in website?

Tags: node.js, database, web

I'm looking to make a website with these features within 2 weeks:

- Account Creation
- Add database entries associated with the current logged in account
- View database entries

I don't know where to start with this. I've looked at the MEAN stack but it is a lot learn for 2 weeks. Would I have to use the entire MEAN stack or would another web stack be better?

Comment: actually it does not cost 2 weeks to learn, when I was starting as beginner to make something with express it cost me 2 days maximum. so have a little enthusiasm, You'll beat it. watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

Comment: Thank you for the video. Addressing the former, would it be the correct stack to use for my use case?

Comment: stack is just a word to describe backend+frontend if i recall correctly.  try learning how to use Node.JS + Express + MongoDB.

Comment: @sova is right, use which tech is comfortable for You, need nodejs so watch the video and learn, not nodejs, so use Laravel (PHP Framework) it would be fast for You to get up and running